# Servlet gets request twice

Tags: java, servlets

I couldn't really get specific with a problem, but SOMETIMES, literally from time to time when i start my jetty server, my login servlet gets GET request twice.

When it happens, login page also doesn't get the css because of this

> "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html".

What i know is that when i disable my filter servlet, everything works fine.

Here's how i add stuff into server:

```
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    CharactersService charactersService = new CharactersService();
    SessionsService sessionsService = new SessionsService();

    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new LoginServlet(userService, charactersService, sessionsService)), "/login");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MainMenuServlet(sessionsService)), "/main");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DuelServlet(userService)), "/duel");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new FightServlet(charactersService, sessionsService, userService)),"/duel/fight");

    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource("src/main/resources"));

    server.setHandler(context);

    ServletHolder defaultHolder = new ServletHolder("default", new DefaultServlet());
    defaultHolder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
    context.addServlet(defaultHolder, "/");

    context.addFilter(new FilterHolder(new AuthenticationFilter()), "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

If i start my server and see that login page get's called twice and doesn't load css, i comment line with addFilter() method, start server, shut it down, uncomment, start it again and login pages loads just fine, which is quite weird.

Is there something wrong with how i add all the stuff to server, or what may even cause such behavior?

Filter servlet code:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String uri = req.getRequestURI();

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    if (session == null && !uri.equals("/login")) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        resp.sendRedirect("/login");
    } else if (session != null && uri.equals("/login")) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        resp.sendRedirect("/main");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not writing logic of Server creation in a static context (static method/block).

Hence, for each request a new server is created. Which results in 2 requests.

Here is an [example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=xapi-master/server/api/src/test/java/xapi/test/server/BasicIOTest.java) of creating a server in static method.

Comment: Server creation is in the main() method, so it's static. And only login servlet get's request twice, other servlets work just fine. The problem seems to be in filter, because when i don't add filter login servlet always works fine.

Comment: Ok, add your web.xml mapping file. Moreover, for each page requests are you getting this issue. Or this issue occurs for first time page reload?

Comment: I don't really have a web.xml, i think it's optional, isn't it?

Comment: remove `chain.doFilter(request, response);` from filter and check the output. It looks like same filter is being called by that code.

Comment: if i remove it completly then no servlet responds to any requests